# Обработка событий при передачи по интерфейсу

Tags: c#, события

Начал писать небольшую программу и возникла проблема с событиями.
Есть такой код:

```cs
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Worker c3 = new();
            c3.c1.SigNotify += C1_SigNotify;
            c3.c2.MyMethod();
        }

        private static bool C1_SigNotify(bool b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello!!!");
            return true;
        }
    }


    interface ISignature
    {
        public delegate bool SigHandler(bool b);
        public event SigHandler SigNotify;

        public void Method();
    }

    // Отвечает за формирование и проверку подписи
    class Signature : ISignature
    {
        public event ISignature.SigHandler SigNotify;

        // проверяет подпись вызывая событие
        public void Method() 
        {
            SigNotify?.Invoke(true);
        }
    }

    // выполняет обработку
    class Logic
    {
        public void MyMethod()
        {
            // и в какой-то момент ставит подпись
            ISignature cls = new Signature();
            cls.Method(); // в нем вызывается событие
        }
    }

    // объединяет логику представляя единую точку входа
    // в идеале все передается по интерфейсам для заменяемости частей программы
    // интерфейс для Logic опущен для уменьшения кода. 
    class Worker
    {
        public ISignature c1 = new Signature(); // подписи
        public Logic c2 = new(); //  обработка
    }
}
```

В текущем коде событие в `Signature` не обрабатывается.
Если перенести событие в класс `Logic` то все работает корректно.
Вопрос как обработать событие в `Signature`? Или стоит переосмыслить структуру программы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну потому что `MyMethod().cls` и `Worker.c1` - разные экземпляры класса `Signature`, обратите внимание, вы вызываете `new Signature()` в двух независимых друг от друга местах кода. В итоге получается, что подписываетесь на событие у одного экземпляра `Signature`, а инвокаете событие у другого.

Исправить можно как-то так:

```cs
class Logic
{
    private ISignature cls;

    public Logic(ISignature signature)
    {
        cls = signature;
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        cls.Method();
    }
}

class Worker
{
    public ISignature c1;
    public Logic c2;

    public Worker()
    {
        c1 = new Signature();
        c2 = new Logic(c1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю все работает )

Answer (score 1):

Так как Logic у вас предназначена для операций над ISignature, она должна содержать ссылку на таковую.

Сейчас вы каждый раз создаете новый экземпляр ISignature, делаете операцию, и уничтожаете объект. Выглядит как бесполезная работа.

Событие же не приходит потому, что вы подписываетесь к другому объекту, ссылки на который в классе Logic нет.